# Sequential throw declarations in my Java code

Tags: java, exception

'Hi, everyone! I have a question about exception handling in Java. What is launched firstly if there is sequential "throw" declarations and why? Below is an example of a method like that:

```
public void myMethod(boolean ok) {
    if (ok) {
        // do something...
    } else {
        throw new myRuntimeException();
        throw new RuntimeException ();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your method ends with the first `throw`s clause. But that's not rocket science, simply try it out.

Comment: This is not valid Java code. It does not compile.make. Asking how it executes is therefore futile.

Answer (score 0):

Most compiler would flag the second "throw" as error : "Unreachable code" - as it will never get executed.

It would be like writing code after a return (except a finally block) - it is never going to get executed - hence illegal.

Comment: *All* compilers. It is an error in Java to write unreachable code.

Answer (score 0):

Once you `throw`, the flow of execution is interrupted and the following happens:

- if you are inside a `try` block, it goes to to the corresponding `catch`
- if not, the Throwable (Exception in your case) is passed up the call chain, leaving `myMethod()` and going to the method that called it

this process is repeated until you either reach a `try` block or the top of the call stack, in which case your program will terminate.

Thus, only your first exception is thrown, the `throw new RuntimeException ();` statement is never reached.